# Cloudflare Worker times out for the client, but all the work completes and no timeout error given (inspected with console.log/ `wrangler tail`)

Tags: cloudflare-workers

My published Cloudflare Worker (`wrangler publish --env environment_name`) is timing out for clients, but **not** when

- running locally (e.g. by using [cfworker](https://github.com/cfworker/cfworker/), a nice tool to emulate cloudflare workers locally)
- or running in preview (`wrangler preview --env environment_name`).

A summary of my worker:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
  const fetchEvent = event as FetchEvent
  const results = await doSomeWork() // returns a promise
  return fetchEvent.respondWith(new Response(JSON.stringify(results)))
})
```

My `wrangler tail` (production logs) output does complete (after I placed `console.log` statements in `doSomeWork`. There were no errors, and I got `{"outcome":"ok"...` in `wrangler tail`. I would have expected to get [error code](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/debugging-workers#identifying-and-handling-errors-and-exceptions) `1102` (Worker exceeded CPU time limit.) if time-out was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `addEventListener` cannot be passed an **async** function (or one that returns a promise). The `fetchEvent.respondWith` does accept a promise however. This is not written in the documentation, but I discovered this in `lib.webworker.d.ts`.

To do asynchronous work, you must return a promise to `fetchEvent.respondWith` instead:

### So your alternatives are to:

- Pass a promise to `respondWith`

```js
addEventListener('fetch' (event) => {
  const fetchEvent = event as FetchEvent
  const responsePromise = doSomeWork().then((results) => new Response(JSON.stringify(results))
  return fetchEvent.respondWith(responsePromise))
})
```

- Or pass the result of an async function to `respondWith` (still a promise, I told you, you must return a promise)

```js
addEventListener('fetch' (event) => {
  const fetchEvent = event as FetchEvent
  const responsePromise = 
  return fetchEvent.respondWith(async () => {
    // I would put this async function in a different file (handlers.ts/.js), and name it `doSomeWorkHandler` to make it more readable though
    const results = await doSomeWork()
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({hello: "world"}))
  }))
})
```

### Why no timeout error?

The reason the timeout error doesn't happen is because even though Cloudflare Workers limits your CPU execution time to 10ms on the free plan, it doesn't stop your **worker** because you're not using the CPU in this bug/ edge case. It's doing nothing.